# Visual Studio C++ 2015 and openMP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openmp, stdlist

I want to know the behaviour of the VC++ compiler with /openmp. I'm using a third party library ([OpenMVG](https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG/)) that comes with the cmakefilelist. So I generated the Visual Studio solution to compile it.
CMake recognizes the openmp capability of the compiler and in VS everithing compiles fine. 
But when it comes to execution, I get different results everythime I run the program. And if I run 2 instances of the program at the same time, the results are even worse.
So I looked a little bit inside the source code and I found out that openmp is used with list and map iterators

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (Views::const_iterator iter = sfm_data.GetViews().begin(); iter != sfm_data.GetViews().end() && bContinue; ++iter)
{
  pragma omp single nowait
  { 
    ... process ... 
  }
}
```

I searched on the web and it seems that Visual Studio only supports openMP 2.0. So does it support list iterators? Can this be the problem? How does openMP 2.0 behave with list iterators?

Thanks in advance fo any answer

Comment: The basic concept of this code is to run the entire loop on all threads, but the inner code of the loop only on single threads. This basically works, but whether this is correct or performs well depends on many things that you don't show. To get a helpful answer, you must provide a [mcve].

Comment: Exactly what did you expect to happen anyway? It's a basic premise in parallel programming that your data structures must be suitable in order for parallelization to work. You can process the list items in parallel, sure, but walking the list is inherently single-threaded. It takes O(N) _sequential_ steps to find the N'th item, no shortcuts.

Comment: As I am getting strange results I was just asking if the fact that Visual Studio implements the version 2.0 of openMP could be the problem, as the library is using list iterators (not supported by 2.0).
I've tried to compile the library without openmp support and the results look stable at every execution

Comment: The [full code](https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG/blob/944254c65691b3b7c5fe54d5bdbe312c90de252f/src/openMVG/sfm/pipelines/sfm_features_provider.hpp) is a reimplementation of a parallel walk over a collection with no random-access iterator without tasks. Everything except a minor race condition that only triggers if there is an error encountered while loading one of the views seems to be compliant with OpenMP 2.0. Either the error occurs somewhere else in the code or the MS OpenMP runtime has trouble implementing overlapping `single` regions. Have you considered filing an issue on GitHub?

Answer (score -1):

The code doesn't do what you probably think it does. It creates a set of threads, each of which executes that same loop.

Note that OpenMP in Visual Studio doesn't really support C++, it treats it as a C dialect. In particular, `/openmp` doesn't support iterators, since that's C++ only. It only supports (some) C loops.

Also note that OpenMP is an old standard, predating even C++98. Since C++11, C++ has native threading capabilities.

Comment: OpenMP is still "regularly" updated, e.g. with atomics support added in 2013 and in that sense not "old". Only VS refused to support any version above OpenMP 2.0. Your last line also suggests that OpenMP and c++ threads are "comparable", but there is a big difference in letting OpenMP setup the threadpool automatically vs. building it yourself

Comment: OpenMP supports C++ random access iterators since 3.0 (2008!). The most recent version of OpenMP is from November 2015, there is a new draft from November 2016. The only issue is Visual Studio implementing a 16 year old version.

Comment: @Zulan: Fair point, made it clearer that I was talking about OpenMP as implemented by Visual Studio. As for "old standard", you could also call it an "early standard" if you like that better. It long provided a capability that C++ lacked until 2011.

Comment: I don't get your last paragraph. C++11 does have built-in threads, but it provides none of the worksharing functionality of OpenMP.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Would you use that for the problem in the question?

Comment: The problem in the question is incomplete. The code as shown makes little sense unless there are explicit OpenMP task constructs within the `single` construct, which is a pretty common idiom.

Comment: I found the full code the OP refers to and consequently retract my previous statement. It's basically a reimplementation of a dynamically scheduled `for` construct for a container class with no random-access iterator type using only constructs from OpenMP 2.0. It could have been implemented using explicit tasks, but those come in later versions of the standard.